# Make computer use 2 monitors as 1

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics-card

I need to make windows use my 2 monitors as 1. End result is any full screen software would see the resolution as ####x####. The idea here being programs that require full screen and bind to 1 monitor would use 2 without complaining.

Surely there is software/drivers for this? If it's any help it's an on-board ATI card and the ATI software for this doesn't function quite as expected with full screen applications. Windowed programs stretch fine but videos, games, virtual machines all continue to use just the 1.

Comment: What is the model number of your ATI card? Starting with the ATI Radeon HD 5000 series, you can use the Eyefinity technology to make two monitors be treated as one display space.

Comment: @nhinkle I believe it is a HD 4800. I must get one of these other ones then!

Comment: FWIW, that /is/ "quite as expected" with full screen applications.  That's traditionally just how it works - full screen rendering can only draw to a single display.  (Eyefinity is the workaround, yes, but I just want to be clear that it's your expectation that's off here and this isn't some ATI-specific thing.)

Comment: @Matt is this a desktop or a laptop? If it's a laptop, you can't replace the graphics card. If it's a desktop, you can do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments above it sounds like your computer has an older Radeon HD 4800. Starting with the HD 5000 series, ATI introduced a technology called [EyeFinity](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/Pages/eyefinity.aspx), which allows you to use multiple displays as one large desktop. In this mode, applications see you as only having one giant monitor, rather than two separate monitors. Maximinizing a window will make it take up all of both screens.

In order for this to work well, you need monitors with identical vertical resolutions. Otherwise, EyeFinity will use the lowest resolution of the two monitors, and will stretch on the other one. Of course, this doesn't look very good.

Any ATI Radeon HD 5000 series or newer will support EyeFinity, but only certain models support more than two simultaneous monitors. If you think you'll be using 3 monitors in the future, make sure to get a card with at least one DisplayPort, as the third (and additional) monitors must be connected by DisplayPort.