# Fullscreen Firefox on two screens

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

I want to use a program (Firefox) in full-screen mode on two screens for presenting. Like a "Kiosk".

When I press <kbd>F11</kbd>, Firefox goes to full screen, but only on one screen.

Comment: What OS are you on? Doesn't seem like a browser-question for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some solutions to make the OS recognizes the two (or more) screens as one like AMD's [Eyefinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Eyefinity). Other alternatives being [UltraView Desktop Manager](https://www.digitaltigers.com/ultraview-desktop-manager.asp) and [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/treat-two-monitors-as-one-ie-merge/?ID=e9f7c9f7-449c-44c9-b5bf-aa108e94d0f2)

> DisplayFusion has hotkey support for window movement, snapping to the sides of the monitors, maximization to span all monitors, and the ability to size windows to a percentage of the work area.

[Make the Most of Your Multiple Monitors in Windows](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1307435/rendering-a-single-fullscreen-window-across-multip.html)

- [How do I make 2 monitors appear as 1 (Stretch Screen)](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2676133/make-monitors-stretch-screen.html)
- [How To Split a 4K Monitor or Divide an Ultrawide Monitor Into Multiple Virtual Monitors](https://www.digitaltigers.com/split-4k-monitor-into-multiple-virtual-monitors.asp)
- [How To Transform Multiple Small Screens Into One Giant Display](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-transform-multiple-screens-into-one-big-virtual-display-2011-3)
- [How to set up a Video Wall in Ventuz](https://youtu.be/6o9pISLdBgI)

You didn't specify the OS, but if it's Windows then this is possibly a duplicate of

- [Make computer use 2 monitors as 1](https://superuser.com/q/345464/241386)
- [Maximize program across multiple monitors](https://superuser.com/q/1173329/241386)
- [How can you maximize a window on to dual monitors in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/186633/241386)

For other OSes

- [Rendering a single fullscreen window across multiple monitors](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1307435/rendering-a-single-fullscreen-window-across-multip.html)
- [How to span a window between two displays in Mavericks](https://www.imore.com/how-span-window-between-two-displays-mavericks)
- [Mac: How to span windows across multiple displays](https://helpcenter.steinberg.de/hc/en-us/articles/206693470-Mac-How-to-span-windows-across-multiple-displays)
- [command to span window across multiple monitors](https://askubuntu.com/q/827435/253474)

You can also use [autoit](https://superuser.com/a/422152/241386), [autohotkey](https://superuser.com/a/1184277/241386) or any other available scripting language to resize the window to span across monitors

Answer (score -1):

i was able to get F11-maximized windows over 3 unified displays using NVidia Mosaic with a Quadro GPU

Comment: it's one of Mosaic's features