# Maximize program across multiple monitors

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

Running Windows 10 with multiple monitors. I can maximize a program in a single monitor by clicking the little box in the top right, or by opening the menu in the program icon on the top left, or by using the window key + up arrow keyboard shortcut, or who knows how many other little shortcuts.

Is there a quick way to maximize a program or window across the whole desktop, including all connected/extended monitors? I'd prefer not to add any third-party software to do this.

I intend to use this mainly for two things: the occasional large spreadsheet, and for remote desktop connections when supporting users who also have multiple displays (mostly via the sccm client rather than the regular remote desktop program), so answers specific to those applications are helpful to me, as well.

Comment: Nvidia/AMD Control Panel can make a single desktop and spread it across multiple monitors.  This allows you to have a single program maximized across multiple monitors.

Comment: Not ideal... most of the time I _don't_ want this, especially as my two displays don't have the same vertical screen resolution. It also falls under the "third-party" rule. Plus, I'm on a laptop with an Intel GPU.

Comment: Installing the drivers for Nvidia/AMD count as third-party?

Comment: It does if you have an Intel GPU. And again, I really want to distinguish between this and the normal behavior.

Comment: You left out that vital information out.  You also can't do it, with those control panels, unless you actually have a Nvidia/AMD GPU obviously.  There is no way to make multiple monitors into unified display with an Intel GPU.  *I am talking where you make 4 monitors into a single display spread across multiple monitors.*

Comment: "I don't want 3rd party" isn't enough of a reason to make a whole new question, especially when the original one even (also) says it prefers native to 3rd party.

Answer (score 8):

This is something I've researched heavily in the past. If you don't want to use third-party software, then I'm fairly certain the answer to your question is no; there is not an easy way to do this natively in Windows 10.

As you might imagine, there are many ways you can accomplish this with third party software. Below are a couple of easy examples, lifted from an older SU question.

If you're comfortable reading/writing scripts, the most lightweight way to do this is probably using something like [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and a simple script. [This SU answer to the same question but for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/a/422152) has a script that will accomplish your goal, using the hotkey of your choosing.

Another answer to the same question references [Dual Monitor Tools](https://superuser.com/a/725408), which I've used in the past, and has this functionality, as described in the answer.

Comment: You can also just line up the top left corner of a floating window with the top left corner of the monitor then stretch/resize the bottom right corner of the window across the monitors without 3rd party software.